# Common WCF Response Handler?

Tags: wcf, inheritance

I have a WCF Client, and the Endpoint has just been upgraded with a new method (OperationContract). I want to write a common method to handle the response from this new method as well as from the existing method at the endpoint.

I am trying to create a "Base" response class and adding common properties to it provided by the WCF endpoint, but I notice in my handler method, the properties are not being retained.

The code for the class I want all responses to inherit from looks like this :

```
public class ResponseBase
{
    public string[] ItemsReturned;
    public bool ItemsWereAvailable;

}
```

So I add partial declarations to get this onto the objects in the endpoint.

```
public partial class RetrieveResponse :ResponseBase
{
}

public partial class RetrieveResponse2 :ResponseBase
{
}
```

This way I have a handler method that just accepts "ResponseBase" as its input.
Am I doing this all wrong?

Comment: Can we see what you're trying to do in your handler method? Also, you don't need to make classes `partial` to get them to inherit from another class, that's used for a [different purpose](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wa80x488(v=vs.80).aspx).

Comment: There is no need to make these classes partial.

Comment: I am trying not to change the classes created by SVCUTIL. Just show the compiler the common fields among the two. I got it working though by commenting out the generated fields and only declaring them in my hand-coded base class.

Answer (score 1):

Any class whose instances will be return values and/or parameters of an operation contract should be decorated with the [DataContract](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractattribute.aspx) attribute, and the properties, as [DataMembers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datamemberattribute.aspx):

```
[DataContract]
public class ResponseBase
{
    [DataMember]
    public string[] ItemsReturned { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public bool ItemsWereAvailable { get; set; }

}
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733127.aspx

If they are not, the [DataContractSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractserializer.aspx) doesn't serialize them.